# Creating a column text box in python

Tags: python

I am working on a school project to make Yahtzee in python ( I am pretty new to the language) and I would like to know if it is possible, and if so, how to have a column of text appear in the command line to display player scores that are updated whenever they decide to score something in a certain category. Here is what I want to print:

```
print:('''
╔═══════════╗╔═══════════╗
║ Ones      ║║           ║
╠═══════════╣╠═══════════╣
║ Twos      ║║           ║
╠═══════════╣╠═══════════╣
║ Threes    ║║           ║
╠═══════════╣╠═══════════╣
║ Fours     ║║           ║
╠═══════════╣╠═══════════╣
║ Fives     ║║           ║
╠═══════════╣╠═══════════╣
║ Sixes     ║║           ║
╠═══════════╣╠═══════════╣
║ Total     ║║           ║
╠═══════════╬╬═══════════╬
╠═══════════╬╬═══════════╬
║ Three of  ║║           ║
║ a kind    ║║           ║
╠═══════════╣╠═══════════╣
║ Four of   ║║           ║
║ a kind    ║║           ║
╠═══════════╣╠═══════════╣
║ Full House║║           ║
╠═══════════╣╠═══════════╣
║ Small     ║║           ║
║ Straight  ║║           ║
╠═══════════╣╠═══════════╣
║ Large     ║║           ║
║ Straight  ║║           ║
╠═══════════╣╠═══════════╣
║ Chance    ║║           ║
╠═══════════╣╠═══════════╣
║ Yahtzee   ║║           ║
╚═══════════╝╚═══════════╝
''')
```

I would like the second column to be duplicated and updated with variables depending on the number of players and what they score in each category. Any ideas would be helpful.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can predefine fix length for box, then print the value and calculate spaces with difference to preserve your structure as follow:

```
box_design_length = 10 # box design length to store character
ones = 2
twos = 55
threes = 4596


print('''
╔═══════════╗╔═══════════╗
║ Ones      ║║ {0}{1}║
╠═══════════╣╠═══════════╣
║ Twos      ║║ {2}{3}║
╠═══════════╣╠═══════════╣
║ Threes    ║║ {4}{5}║
╚═══════════╝╚═══════════╝
'''.format(ones, ' '*(box_design_length-len(str(ones))),
    twos, ' '*(box_design_length-len(str(twos))), 
    threes, ' '*(box_design_length-len(str(threes))), 
    )
)
```

`format()` do string formatting
`{0}, {1}, {2}...` are the number of argument passed in `format()` which supports all python versions above 2.6

Output:

```
╔═══════════╗╔═══════════╗
║ Ones      ║║ 2         ║
╠═══════════╣╠═══════════╣
║ Twos      ║║ 55        ║
╠═══════════╣╠═══════════╣
║ Threes    ║║ 4596      ║
╚═══════════╝╚═══════════╝
```

If you are aware with [python formatting](https://pyformat.info/) you can do it in much better ways as shown below:

```
from collections import OrderedDict
values = OrderedDict([('Ones', 2), ('twos', 55), ('threes', 4596)])  # store key, value in dictionary
# order dictionary is used to preserve order

def box_printer(value_set, box_design_length):
    """
     print values in box
    :param value_set: dictionary of key and value to print in box
    :param box_design_length: length of box design
    """
    count = 0  # initialize count: help to identify first loop or last loop to change box design accordingly

    for key, value in value_set.items():
        if count == 0: # first loop
            print('╔{0}╗╔{0}╗'.format('═'*box_design_length))
        count += 1
        print('║ {1:^{0}}║║ {2:^{0}}║'.format(box_design_length-1, key, value))
        if count >= len(value_set):
            print('╚{0}╝╚{0}╝'.format('═'*box_design_length))
        else:
            print('╠{0}╣╠{0}╣'.format('═'*box_design_length))

box_printer(values, 11)
```

You will get your desire output with this code.

Comment: could you make the box able to be expanded sideways, based on the number of people playing the game?
like this:                                                             
╔═══════════╗╔═══════════╗╔═══════════╗
║ Ones                   ║║                            ║║                            ║
╠═══════════╣╠═══════════╣╠═══════════╣
║ Twos                   ║║                            ║║                            ║
╠═══════════╣╠═══════════╣╠═══════════╣
║ Threes                ║║                            ║║                            ║
╚═══════════╝╚═══════════╝╚═══════════╝

Comment: @BrianMcglinchey could you please elaborate more?

Answer (score 0):

If you are using python 3.6 then [f-strings](https://docs.python.org/3.6/reference/lexical_analysis.html#f-strings) would be ideal.

```
t = 3
text = (f'''
╔═══════════╗╔═══════════╗
║ Ones      ║║    {t}    ║
╠═══════════╣╠═══════════╣
║ Twos      ║║           ║
╠═══════════╣╠═══════════╣
''')
print(text)
```

The t variable is added using curly braces and converted when the text variable is used.

Comment: his design of column will be depend on length of digit in `t` if t will be higher or lower then expected design will not look the same

Comment: @Gahan agreed a limit would have to be defined on the values to fit the design.
If the max value(i.e. 100) is known then zero padding the variable t would solve this for smaller values. i.e {t:03d} would pad t to 003

Comment: Only the yahtzee category has digit 100 all others would only be two digits